# How to import 'url-regex' npm package in Angular(2/4)?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I use Angular 4 and have trouple using [url-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex) package in my Component.

In some cases, I have found out that this works:

```
import * as urlRegex from 'url-regex';
```

But does not work in my case, inside `constructor()` and `ngOnInit()`, the value of `urlRegex` is `undefined`.

This is the [index.js](https://github.com/kevva/url-regex/blob/master/index.js) file from this package

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add full code or upload the code to github and send me the link to github, so that I can test on myside.

Comment: You should write `import urlRegex from 'url-regex';` instead of using a namespace (`* as`) import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After import, if I **call** `urlRegex()` anywhere inside the Component it works!

At debugging in the Browser, when I hover over `urlIndex()` it shows `(anonymous)`;
[image]

Probably it has to do with the import of Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

There's a default export (you can see this if you use VScode or a similar editor), so rather than importing everything with `import *`, just use:

`import urlRegex from "url-regex"`

Then to produce the RegExp, run `urlRegex()`